# Remove underscores from all filenames within a directory

Tags: unix, command-line, scripting, replace, filenames

I have a folder "model" with files named like:

```
a_EmployeeData
a_TableData
b_TestData
b_TestModel
```

I basically need to drop the underscore and make them:

```
aEmployeeData
aTableData
bTestData
bTestModel
```

Is there away in the Unix Command Line to do so?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to rename the files or just print out the filenames without underscore?

Comment: Decide what you want to do if `foo_bar' and 'foobar' both exist.

Comment: They don't... for sure.

Comment: Rename the files please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will correctly process files containing odd characters like spaces or even newlines and should work on any Unix / Linux distribution being only based on POSIX syntax.

```
find model -type f -name "*_*" -exec sh -c 'd=$(dirname "$1"); mv "$1" "$d/$(basename "$1" | tr -d _)"' sh {} \;
```

Here is what it does:

For each file (not directory) containing an underscore in its name under the model directory and its subdirectories, rename the file in place with all the underscores stripped out.

Comment: nitpick: it doesn't work for files in directories whose name ends in newline characters. If omitting `-type f`, you need to add a `-depth`.

Comment: If you've got a `ab`, `a_b` and `a__b` files, you'll lose two of them (or move `a_b` and `a__b` inside `ab` if `ab` is a directory. You may want to add a `-i` to `mv` (and add the GNU-specific `-T` option) or go with `zmv` that guards against that.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You are (as almost always) correct. These are however corner cases that are very unlikely to hit the OP so might not be worth considering. In particular the name clash issue seems to be ruled out in one of gran_profaci's comment.

Comment: This works nice if you remove model from the command and go directly to the source directory (it will rename in place). 

 find  -type f -name "*_*" -exec sh -c 'd=$(dirname "$1"); mv "$1" "$d/$(basename "$1" | tr -d _)"' sh {} \;

Answer (score 5):

You can do this simply with `bash`.

```
for file in /path/to/model/*; do
mv "$file" "${file/_/}"
done
```

If you have `rename` command available then simply do

```
rename 's/_//' /path/to/model/*
```

Comment: This definitely worked!, don't remember to add `\ ` instead of a space ` ` when defining the path!

Comment: maybe to avoid warnings etc. in case you also have files without underscores in the same directory, you can adjust to `for file in /path/to/model/_*; do...`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for f in model/* ; do mv "$f" `echo "$f" | sed 's/_//g'` ; done
```

Edit: modified a few things thanks to suggestions by others, but I'm afraid my code is still bad for strange filenames.

Comment: it's unsafe to use `\`ls model\``, among other things if the filenames have spaces it wouldn't work right (I know OP's example doesn't have it, but we should try to avoid possible scenarios like this)

Comment: you can use `for f in model/*` - don't need the useless `ls model`

Answer (score 1):

maybe this:

```
find model -name "*_*" -type f -maxdepth 1 -print |  sed -e 'p;s/_//g' | xargs -n2 echo mv
```

Decomposition:

- find all `plain files` in the directory `model` what contains at least one underscore, and don't search subdirectories
- with the `sed` make filename adjustments - replace the `_` with nothing
- also print the old name
- fed the two filenames to `xargs` what will rename the files with `mv`

The above is for a dry-run. When satisfied, remove the `echo` before `mv` for actual rename.

Warning: Will not work if filename contains spaces. If you have `GNU sed` you can

```
find . -name "*_*" -maxdepth 1 -print0 |  sed -z 'p;s/_//g' | xargs -0 -n2 echo mv
```

and will works with a filenames with spaces too...

Answer (score 1):

In zsh:

```
autoload zmv # in ~/.zshrc
cd model && zmv '(**/)(*)' '$1${2//_}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my machine, but the filenames had more than one underscore. I used `rename` with the `g` option so that all underscores get removed:

```
find model/ -maxdepth 1 -type f | rename 's/_//g'
```

Or if there are no subdirectories, just

```
rename 's/_//g'
```

If you don't have `rename`, see [Jaypal Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17285790/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

```
marc@panic:~$ echo 'a_EmployeeData' | tr -d '_'
aEmployeeData
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the global flag `/g` with your replace pattern to replace all occurrences within the filename.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/_//g'
```

Or if you want underscores replaced with spaces then use this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/_/ /g'
```

If you like to live dangerously add the force flag `-f` in front of your replace pattern `rename -f 's/_//g'`